# Criar um alerta na tela quando um horário especifico for atingido

Tags: javascript

Estou com a seguinte função:

```
function time() {
  let today = new Date();
  today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 30);
  let h = today.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let m = today.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let s = today.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
}
```

Essa função é acionada quando aperto um botão. Porém precisava que quando o horário que é jogado no HTML (no caso a hora local + 30 min) fosse o horário local, emitisse um `alert` padrão ou um pop up, com uma mensagem ao usuário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta calcular a diferença (em milissegundos) entre a data atual e a data na qual você quer emitir o alerta, passando esse intervalo para o segundo argumento do [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Como você já tem a instância da data "do futuro", pode fazer algo assim:

```js
function time() {
  let future = new Date();
  future.setMinutes(future.getMinutes() + 30);
  let h = future.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let m = future.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let s = future.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
  
  let interval = future.getTime() - Date.now();
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('30 minutos se passaram.');
  }, interval);
}
```

Observe que renomeei `today` para `future` só para ficar um pouco mais claro. Note também que [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) retorna o *timestamp* atual, em milissegundos.

Vale lembrar que, se o usuário sair da página, o *timeout* perderá o efeito.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Saberia me dizer se é possível acionar um alerta sonoro? Alguma biblioteca talvez?

Comment: @Riberox, se você tiver o URL do arquivo de áudio, pode utilizar a API nativa [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio). Ele retorna um `HTMLAudioElement` que possui um método [`play`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) que pode ser usado para tocar o som.